# How to find the emitter Spinbox from a valueChanged Signal?

Tags: pyqt, signals-slots, sender

I have several Spinboxes and I want them to change the background color, if the value is changed.

With this connect command:

```
self.doubleSpinBox_1.valueChanged.connect(self.color)
```

My first try was:

```
def color(self):
   send = self.sender()
   emitter = send.text()
```

The Problem is, that "send.text()" returns the changed value, and not the spinbox witch emmited the signal.
In the documentation about QDoubleSpinBox I searched for something like "setName", or something to identify my sender-spinbox, but I didnt find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self.sender()` **is** the spinbox which emitted the signal. You are effectively calling `doubleSpinBox_1.text()` which of course gives you the text in the spinbox.

So just write `mySpinBox = self.sender()` and you will be right.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `is` operator to identify the sender:

```
def color(self):
    spinbox = self.sender()
    if spinbox is self.doubleSpinBox_1:
        # do something with doubleSpinBox_1
    elif spinbox is self.doubleSpinBox_2:
        # do something with doubleSpinBox_1
    ...
```

But if really *do* want to give your widgets a name, you can use [setObjectName](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#objectName-prop) for that:

```
    self.doubleSpinBox_1.setObjectName('spinbox1')
    print(self.doubleSpinBox_1.objectName())
```

PS: if your widgets were created via Qt Designer, they will automatically have their `objectName` set (it will be the same as their attribute name).